# FIle Not Found on Site Content and Structure

Tags: error, content-and-structure

When I go to *Site Content and Structure* on the root site of my site collection I am getting:

> File Not Found.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: dedfa27c-c920-4f32-b9d5-71b6c6fc3ad3
>
> Date and Time: 10/26/2011 12:30:25 PM

The URL I am hitting is http://mysite/sites/site_collection_name/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx.

How I can I find the page?

Comment: Did you finally manage to solve it?

Comment: Is that from the Site Actions menu or have you just typed in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would check is the ULS logs. Grab that correlation ID and see what you can find about the error being produced. Not necessarily the resolution to the issue but will give more info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently deactivate a feature?  I have also seen this error when a content type was in use then improperly deleted as part of feature deactivation or when it was deleted manually with the original feature still active.